vscode shortcut for running one line after another
I was trying to create a shortcut in vscode, python, for CTRL+enter to run one line (as in R) but i says ' 'editor.action.selectLine' not found'

installed necessary extensions, code-runner and multi command
in keybindings.json:
enter image description here
in settings.json:
enter image description here

Now, when i'm trying to run one line, it says 'command 'editor.action.selectLine' not found
when I change command 'editor.action.selectLine'  to alternative one:  //"cursorLineStartSelect", the same happens with last command: command "cursorMoveDown" not found
